# Regulated Power Supply

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, 7805

I am supposed to simulate this circuit (regulated power supply 5V), however I am not understanding what's the point of the resistor R. Is it a load resistor? Cause i thought these needed to be before the regulator.
[image: circuit]

Comment: yes. it's a load resistor.

Comment: @KingDuken:  I don't see anything to do with current regulation in the OP's schematic.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a typical [7805 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78.pdf)  you'll find a statement like

*Note: Minimum load current for regulation is 5 mA*

If the circuit is expected to maintain a 5V output with a load going right down to zero, the resistor R ensures that enough current is drawn from the 7805 to guarantee that the 5mA minimum is met. In this case a 1000 Ohm resistor would be needed.

It's often not seen in the real world because the 7805 will normally be built into a circuit that will always take at least the minimum load.

Answer (score 0):

As you adjust \$R\$ in your simulation, you should be able to see the input voltage (across \$C\$) go up or down, but the voltage across \$R\$ should remain relatively constant.